# Flash security sandbox: calling a Javascript that makes a call to a different site

Tags: javascript, flash, security, sandbox, crossdomain.xml

Edit: I mixed a.com and b.com in my original post, I'll try to rephrase stuff correctly:

- A HTML page is loaded from a.com
- The HTML embeds a Flash client from b.com
- HTML contains a Javascript function that makes a connection to a.com, ie the origin of the HTML, not the origin of Flash
- The Flash calls that Javascript function

Question: Do I need to have a crossdomain.xml in a.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide more details
and in the meantime take a look at flash parameter :

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
```

"sameDomain" is the default value
As said in http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html

> When AllowScriptAccess is "always",
>   the SWF file can communicate with the
>   HTML page in which it is embedded even
>   when the SWF file is from a different
>   domain than the HTML page.

Comment: I made some changes to the original post. I need to know if the Javascript called by the Flash client is allowed to connect to its origin.

Comment: As said in the adobe page : "The AllowScriptAccess parameter in the HTML code that loads a SWF file controls the ability to perform outbound URL access from within the SWF file."

You won't need a crossdomain (crossdomain is for blazeds) but you'l need <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />

Answer (score 2):

Cross - domain restrictions are enforced in Javascript by the browser (normally). Depending on what you need to do, however, there are a number of workarounds. Perhaps if you provided more details?

---

EDIT:

You will need to use

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

Cross - domain SWFs cannot normally access a web page, unless you use this, due to trust issues.

Comment: I hade a mistake in my original post and also rephrased the thing, maybe it's more clear now?

Comment: I 've updated my post as well. Check it out and see if it works for you. Unfortunately, I can't test it at the moment. Oh, and you don't need a crossdomain.xml file.